# App Engine endpoint to accept POST data in request body

Tags: google-app-engine

I have created a Google Endpoint in my App Engine Server as follows:

```
package com.xxxxx.gcmbackend;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.inject.Named;

import static com.xxxxxx.gcmbackend.OfyService.ofy;

@Api(
        name = "register",
        version = "v1",
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(
                ownerDomain = "gcmbackend.xxxxx.com",
                ownerName = "gcmbackend.xxxxx.com",
                packagePath=""
        )
)


public class UserRegistrationEndpoint {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RegistrationEndpoint.class.getName());
    @ApiMethod(name = "register")
    public void registerDevice(@Named("regId") String regId, @Named("username") String username, @Named("phone") String phone) {
        if(findRecord(regId) != null) {
            log.info("Device " + regId + " already registered, skipping register");
            return;
        }
        RegistrationRecord record = new RegistrationRecord();
        record.setRegId(regId);
        record.setUsername(username);
        record.setPhone(phone);
        ofy().save().entity(record).now();
    }
    private RegistrationRecord findRecord(String regId) {
        return ofy().load().type(RegistrationRecord.class).filter("regId", regId).first().now();
    }
}
```

This works perfectly in creating new `User` records. The API is of the following format:

```
http://example.appspot.com/_ah/api/register/v1/registerDevice/<regId>/<username>/<phone>
```

However, I want the url to look like this:

```
http://example.appspot.com/_ah/api/register/v1/registerDevice/
```

and then send POST data as follows:

```
{
    regId: "some_value",
    username: "some_value",
    phone: "some_value"
}
```

What do I need to change in my Endpoint in order to achieve this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a java bean with `regId`, `username` and `phone` attributes e.g. `RegistrationInput`.

```
public class RegistrationInput {
    private String regId;
    private String username;
    private String phone;

    public String getRegId() {
        return regId;
    }

    public void setRegId(String regId) {
        this.regId = regId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Then add the above java bean `RegistrationInput`, as a parameter to the `ApiMethod`

```
@ApiMethod(name = "register")
public void registerDevice(RegistrationInput input) {
    .....
}
```

Comment: Hey! Could you explain it a bit further? I'm new to Java so I'm not really sure what you mean by Java bean and how it would look like.

Comment: Updated the answer. A java bean is a simple class with few attributes. It also has getter and setter methods for each of the attributes.